# BroadcastReceiver TTS and Volume

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, text-to-speech, volume

I have a BroadCastReceiver that starts a background service. This service speaks some text using TTS. Since it all starts with a BroadcastReceiver, there is no UI.

I want to give the user an opportunity to mute when he presses volume down key.

Please guide me how this is possible. I have seen few other related questions but did not get any clear idea. Is it possible to do or not. Please suggest.

Your response is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your App can not responds any broadcast until user start it explicitly.It means that:The **application must first be invoked by the user through of activity**,and so your App has to have at least on Activity and **UI**.